# TextMate CSS autocompletion

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, textmate

Recently I updated my installation of TextMate and I have noticed something rather annoying. When writing CSS code, it no longer automatically appends the semicolon. Here is how it was if I typed "background:":

```
#someDiv { background: ; }
```

and now it no longer adds that semicolon:

```
#someDiv { background: }
```

It really saved me a bunch of time when it automatically provided that semicolon. Has anyone else noticed this or know how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the file saved as .css or the selector at the bottom of the window set to CSS?

When I do either of those the semicolon gets added automatically...

Maybe your update did something to the CSS bundle?  You could try to update the CSS bundle and reload bundles to see if that helps.